# Print specific character when pressing specific keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to insert a specific character when pressing, for example, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. The characters i want to insert is an upsidedown exclamation mark and an upsidedown question mark.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster is one of many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript keydown event object contains an "altKey" and "ctrlKey" property which tell you whether those keys were pressed when the event fired. Attach a keydown event to your element and check for those two flags along with the keyCode you're interested in:

```
$(".your-element").on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==49 && e.altKey && e.ctrlKey){
        $(this).val($(this).val()+String.fromCharCode(161));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect a sequence of key presses you can do something like this:

```
var keys = [];

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  keys = [];
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  keys.push(event.keyCode);

  if (keys.toString() === [17, 18, 49].toString()) {
    console.log('You pressed CTRL+ALT+1');
  }
});
```